# provide details

Tags: word-choice

Is it "is" or "are"?

4. Ceiling height issues with bulkheads is being reviewed by joint commission. GTG will follow up on all reviews to make sure that no deadlines are compromised.

Comment: Issues= are. Ceiling height=is. Issues makes it plural. ceiling height is adjectival (or adjunctive, if you prefer that lingo).

Comment: What does the title of this question refer to? Please make your title describe the subject matter of the question.

Answer (score 1):

If it mentions `ceiling height issues`, I think that will call for plural, so I believe it should be `are`